# Deduping Sqlite3 Table With No Key

Tags: sql, sqlite

I forgot to create an index and now I'm trying to remove rows that have the same value in one column. How do I do that, I'm stumped.

Thanks!

Comment: you need to provide more detail , the table schema  and sample data

Comment: General observation: It's usually easier to copy rows you want to keep to a new table than to delete from the existing table. Typically you could add a sequence number to the "duplicates" using a subquery (e.g. with `ROW_NUMBER` function) and then have the main query only keep rows with sequence number 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have created the table [without rowid](https://www.sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html), your table has [`rowid` as `PRIMARY KEY`](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html).
Use it to delete the duplicates:

```
DELETE FROM tablename
WHERE rowid NOT IN (
  SELECT MAX(rowid) 
  FROM tablename
  GROUP BY columnname
)
```

Change `columnname` to the name of the column that is duplicated.
See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=2e43858e5b2081471eee075af4a21ade).

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Done!

I'm a bit new to Stack Overflow. Is there some equivalent of Reddit Karma on here I can give you?

Comment: @DanIrwin I don't know what a Reddit Karma is. When your rep reaches 15 (I think) you will also be able to upvote answers by clicking on the up arrow.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you need to refresh the values of `id` column so as to be unique, create a new table such as

```
CREATE TABLE tab2(
   ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
   <other columns within the "tab" table>
)
```

and populate that table by using analytic function `ROW_NUMBER()`

```
INSERT INTO tab2
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS id, the other columns
  FROM tab t
```

and then rename `tab2` to `tab` after dropping `tab`

```
DROP TABLE tab;
ALTER TABLE tab2 RENAME TO tab
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=c5ebeae9805d26373081bfa5b5bb7c82)</kbd>